# Are homotopy equivalences homotopic to each other?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Given spaces $X,Y$ and homotopy equivalences $f,g:X\to Y$, do we have $f\simeq g$?

I know that the converse is true: a map homotopic to a homotopy equivalence is also a homotopy equivalence. But for this question I can't think of any counterexamples.

Comment: As stated, obviously no: it would mean that any two automorphisms of $X$ are homotopic, which is false for eg $S^1$.

Comment: See the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3896664/are-weak-homotopy-equivalences-always-homotopic/3896768#3896768).

Comment: Because this question (and more) is answered in the link given by Tyrone, I am closing as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Take $X = Y = \{-1,1\}$ with the discrete topology and $f(x) = x$, $g(x) = -x$.